# Determining if a MIME email part is a file or message text

Tags: python, email, mime, email-attachments, email-headers

As part of some email batch processing, we need to decode and *clean up* the messages.  One critical part of that process is separating the mail bodies of a message and the mail attachments.  The trickiest part is to determine when a `Conent-Disposition: inline` part is to be considered a message body alternative or a file.

So far, this code seems to handle most of the cases:

```
from email import message_from_string

def split_parts(raw):
    msg = message_from_string(raw)
    bodies = []
    files = []

    for sub in msg.walk():
        if sub.is_multipart():
            continue
        cd = sub.get("Content-Disposition", "")
        if cd.startswith("attachment") or (cd.startswith("inline") and
                                           sub.get_filename()):
            files.append(sub)
        else:
            bodies.append(sub)

    return bodies, files
```

Note the reliance on the inline parts to have a filename specified in the headers, which Outlook seems to do for all its `multipart/related` messages.  The `Content-ID` could also be used as a hint, but according to the [RFC 2387](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2387) it is not such an indicator.

Therefore, if an embedded image is encoded as a message part that has `Content-Disposition: inline`, defines a `Content-ID` and doesn't have a filename then the above code can mistakenly classify it as a message body alternative.

From what I've read from the RFC's, there's not much hope on finding an easy check (specially since coding according to the RFCs is almost useless in the real world, because nobody does it); but I was wondering how big the chances are to hit the misclassification case.

---

### Rationale

I could have a set of functions to treat each `multipart/*` case and let them indirectly recurse.  However, we don't care so much about a faithful display; as a matter of fact, we filter all HTML messages through [tidy](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/).  Instead, we are more interested in chosing one of the message body alternatives and saving as many attachments as possible, even if they are intended to be embedded.

Furthermore, some user agents do really weird things when composing `multipart/alternative` messages with embedded attachments that are not intended to be displayed inline (such as PDF files), as a result of the user dragging and dropping an arbitrary file into the composition window.

Comment: I don't think there is any one standard way to do this.  If you want to simulate how a client would handle these messages, implement your own preferences for how to pick one part out of a set of `multipart/alternative` (or in practice I guess also `multipart/mixed` and `multipart/related` and and and ...) and declare the others as "attachments".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not quite following you, but, if you want bodies, I would assume anything with a text/plain or text/html content type, with an inline content disposition, with no file name or no content-id, could be a body part.

Comment: I just re-read [section 3.2 from RFC 2387](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2387#section-3.2) a bit more carefully and I guess I'll have to resign myself assuming the reality that nobody actually seem to use the `start` parameter of `multipart/related` containers.  Until I find a case, which will force me to add complexity to my little, simple and cute function.